# PHP com PDO retornando registros BLOB com foreach

Tags: php, pdo, oracle, foreach, blob

Boa tarde pessoal, sou novo aqui (primeira pergunta), mas o Stack já me ajudou em várias situações.

Eis o problema:

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e em determinada página existe uma página perfil do usuário. Nesta página, uma div que apresenta as fotos dos usuários que pertencem ao mesmo setor que o usuário logado.

Query:

```
$query3 = "SELECT USR.EMAIL, USR.IMG_PERFIL, IMG.IMAGEM FROM IN_USUARIOS USR, IN_IMAGENS IMG WHERE USR.IMG_PERFIL = IMG.ID AND USR.SETOR =:setor AND USR.ID !=:id";
```

Executando:

```
$stmt3 = $conn->prepare($query3);
$stmt3->bindValue(':setor',$result1['SETOR']);
$stmt3->bindValue(':id',$result1['ID']);
$stmt3->execute();
$result3=$stmt3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

*$result1 = Retorna todos os dados do usuário

Listando:

```
 <ul class="friends">
  <?php
   foreach($result3 as $key => $value ) 
    { 
      echo
        '<li>
          <div class="profile-pic">
            <img width="35" height="35" title="'. $value['EMAIL'] .'" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode(stream_get_contents($value['IMAGEM'])).'">
          </div>
         </li>';
    }
  ?
```

O código apresenta as imagens, porém sempre a mesma, no caso a imagem do último colega no array de dados: (deveria vir a imagem correspondente a cada um dos colegas do usuário logado.

[image: Print]

- percebam que vai um title na imagem de acordo com o email do colega, isto está funcionando, trazendo os emails de cada um dos colegas.

var_dump($result3):

```
    array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["EMAIL"]=>
    string(30) "fernando.horbach@xxxx.com.br"
    ["IMG_PERFIL"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["IMAGEM"]=>
    resource(3) of type (stream)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["EMAIL"]=>
    string(29) "ronaldo.ribeiro@xxxx.com.br"
    ["IMG_PERFIL"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["IMAGEM"]=>
    resource(4) of type (stream)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["EMAIL"]=>
    string(26) "fabio.geiger@xxxx.com.br"
    ["IMG_PERFIL"]=>
    string(1) "7"
    ["IMAGEM"]=>
    resource(5) of type (stream)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["EMAIL"]=>
    string(26) "joao.gustavo@xxxx.com.br"
    ["IMG_PERFIL"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["IMAGEM"]=>
    resource(6) of type (stream)
  }
```

}

- Visualizando código da página:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Devo estar esquecendo algum detalhe nesse meu foreach. Conto com a ajuda de vocês.

Obrigado.

Comment: dá um var_dump($result3); antes do foreach e ve se os dados estão todos lá...

Comment: @LocalHost Adicionei o var_dump($result3); a pergunta, veja.

Comment: tenta colocar como coloquei na resposta ali, se nao der comente. Vou analisar melhor aqui

Comment: @LocalHost continua apresentando o mesmo resultado. Cliquei com o botão direito "visualizar código fonte", fui até a parte do código que deveria trazer as imagens e observei que o hash da imagem em base64 é a mesma... (Adicionei a imagem a pergunta)

Comment: Duas perguntas. Primeira, qual a razão de usar diferente em vez de igual aqui? `USR.ID !=:id` e segunda,  `USR.IMG_PERFIL = IMG.ID` é IMG_PERFIL mesmo o campo de ID de perfil das imagens?

Comment: @Bacco Resposta 1: Pois quero trazer todos do mesmo setor (USR.SETOR=:setor) menos o usuário logado (USR.ID !=:id). Resposta 2: IMG_PERFIL é um campo na tabela de usuários que tem uma FK para a tabela de imagens, onde a PK é a o campo ID.

Comment: Um detalhe estranho, mas que pode nos ajudar é que dependendo do usuário que está logado, a imagem que se repete muda. Ex: Logado como GABRIEL a imagem que se repete nos colegas é do usuário JOÃO, logado como FÁBIO a imagem que se repete é do GABRIEL, etc...

Comment: essa PK é  o campo ID do usuário?

Comment: @Bacco PK=Primary Key, é a chave da tabela, ou seja, não pode se repetir. É um id único por registro. na tabela de imagens, por exemplo, é o campo ID que é um number(6) e na tabela usuários a PK é EMAIL que é um varchar2(35). Estou usando banco Oracle.

Comment: na verdade agora que eu passei a query a limpo aqui pra entender melhor, ficou meio ruim de ler na pergunta.

Comment: A pergunta é meio estranha, mas você já fez uma listagem simples usuário e foto, só pra ver se estão corretos os pares no DB?